# UIScrollview with paging and interaction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I am trying to wrap my head around how this would work. I want to create a horizontal scrollview consisting of "tiles" that are added and that you can scroll through (paging). On each tile will be a main image and other various smaller images that will act as buttons and launch popovers and such. I understand that I can create my "tile" as a uiview subclass programmatically or in a viewcontroller which then can have it's view added to the main uiscrollview. My question is where do I detect touch events of the small button-like elements in each tile? Would the main viewcontroller that manages the scrollview be the one that would handle the touches of the subviews' subviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would detect the touch events for your tiles in whatever view handler you have them in. Basically you would have one view with a scroll view on it, then you would create another view that would have your tiles, within the view that contains your tiles is where you would handle the touch events for them, but you will have to keep track of which "Page" you are on to know what actions should be performed.

[This is the best example I have found on using the page controls.](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/05/22/iphone-uiscrollview-with-paging-example/)